# Populating a combobox from a table in Webmatrix using CHTML

Tags: html, combobox, webmatrix

I'm a newby and am using Webmatrix (CHTML) to try and set up a form that allows the user to select an employee using a dropdownbox.
I think I understand how to make a list:

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("DatabaseName") ;
var selectCommand="SELECT ID,Employee FROM Employees";
var selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand);
var columns = new[]{"ID", "Employee"};
var grid = new WebGrid(source: selectedData, defaultSort: "Employee" , rowsPerPage:10,columnNames: columns);  
}
@grid.GetHtml(  )
```

and I think I know how to get a combobox:

```
<FORM NAME="myform">
<SELECT NAME="mylist">
<OPTION VALUE="01">Employee01
<OPTION VALUE="02">Employee02
<OPTION VALUE="03">Employee03
<OPTION VALUE="04">Employee04
<OPTION VALUE="05">Employee05 - and so on
</SELECT>
</FORM>
```

I just want to know how to get the table into the combobox.  Would be very happy if someone could show how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

This code creates a dropdown list from the content of your table:

```
@{   
    var db = Database.Open("DatabaseName");
    var selectCommand = "SELECT ID, Employee FROM Employees";
    var selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand); 
} 

<form name="myform" method="post">
    <select name="mylist">
        @foreach(var row in selectedData)
        {
            <option value="@row.ID">@row.Employee</option>
        }
    </select>
</form>
```